# XDB Contact is interaction is not created in XDB database -10.2

Tags: xdb

I have installed the Vannila instance of Sitecore 10.2 and added a standard `MVC Layout` with `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` and created one sample form with First name, Last Name, and Email after that mapped with the page and assign submit action.

Now, Visited the page and submitted the form. The data is saved on the form database.

```
Note: 
1. I have enabled Anonymous as a true
2. Enabled PIISensitive data as a true
3. Submitted the form and close the browser for session close.
```

There is no interaction is displaying in the expericence profile and Last visit duration.

[image]

Comment: Did you check that the `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` is set to `true` in the `App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Xdb.config` configuration file?

Comment: That is already enabled in the file

Comment: Are you doing this on contentmanagement role? If so try standalone or contentdelivery

Comment: I'm using content management role

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the following things on your solution to make it work.

- Rebuild All Indexes from Control Panel
- Build Link Databases
- Go to your xConnect instance and enable tracking of anonymous users in `App_data\Config\sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`  and `App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\config\sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml` by updating the below setting to true

  ```
  <IndexAnonymousContactData>true</IndexAnonymousContactData>
  ```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Did you check these settings?

Comment: I have already enabled all the settings, Now I have rebuild the link database and rebuild all the index then the latest interaction is showing now. I will recheck and confim

Comment: @Rameshkumar Great.

Comment: @Rameshkumar Did it solve your issue?

Comment: No It is not solved.

Comment: @Rameshkumar Try this one also. From the control panel -> Deploy Marketing Definitions.

Comment: could you add a goal to the form/page where the form is added, resubmit the form and check if you see the interaction?

Answer (score 0):

In order to track analytics data to the correct database please check the following:

- check whether the "collection" connection string is pointed to the right `ShardMapManager` database;
- check whether xConnect connection strings on CD instances are pointed to the correct xConnect;
- check whether the correct server name and database name is set in the following tables:

  ```
  [_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager].[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal]
  [_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[__ShardManagement].[ShardsLocal]
  [_Xdb.Collection.Shard1].[__ShardManagement].[ShardsLocal]
  ```

If everything is set correctly please try to restart CD and xConnect instances and check whether the issue is reproducible afterwards.

The absence of data in the Experience Profile could be due to the following reasons:

1. There are no identified contacts in Shards. By default indexing of anonymous contacts is disabled. In order to enable it please refer to the following article: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html
2. In case there are identified contacts in Shards and you do not want to enable indexing of anonymous contacts in order to see data in Exp Profile please perform the rebuild of the xdb index: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html

Please be sure that `IndexPIISensitiveData` setting in the `sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml` file is `true` in the `xdbsearch` and in the `xdbsearchworker` instances.
Please run rebuild on your `xdbsearchworker` instance using `.\Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr` command.